# Connect ColdFusion 11 to Remote Solr

Tags: apache, solr, coldfusion

I am having trouble "connecting" my stand-alone Solr server to my ColdFusion 11 Enterprise server. It seems that I have the basic Solr server information correct in the CFIDE Admin, but ColdFusion isn't listing any collections/cores which exist on the Solr server. Also, I cannot create new collections/cores using the ColdFusion admin gui.

In CFIDE Admin I have set the Solr server information as follows:

> Solr Host Name: 172.xx.xxx.xx
>   Solr Home: /opt/bitnami/apache-solr/solr
>   Solr Admin Port: 8983
>   Solr Webapp: solr
>   Solr Buffer Limit: 40
>   User name: [blank]
>   Password: [blank]
>   Solr Connection: [ ] Use HTTPS connection (not checked)
>   Solr Admin HTTPS Port: 0 (not using HTTPS at this time)

Here is what I see in the CFIDE Admin when I try and create a new collection:

> Unable to create collection test-collection.
>   Unable to create Solr collection test-collection.
>   An error occurred while creating the collection: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException. Check the Solr logs for more detail.

And this is what I see from the same action in the Solr logs:

> CoreContainer
>   Error creating core [test-collection]: Could not load conf for core test-collection: Error loading solr config from /opt/bitnami/apache-solr/solr/test-collection/conf/solrconfig.xml
>   SolrCore
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'test-collection': Unable to create core [test-collection] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/opt/bitnami/apache-solr/solr/test-collection/conf'

I've searched for quite a while and haven't found anything that helps me connect ColdFusion 11 to a remote Solr server. I much appreciate any help you can give me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Matt, I don't think you can use CF to create a collection on a remote Solr server. Is your "standalone" Solr server also a CF server? You can always use Solr admin itself to create the new core.

Comment: @David That may be true, but I think there's a bigger problem because I can't even see the existing collections in the Coldfusion admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Adobe and (surprisingly) received some help. They said non-ColdFusion Solr servers are officially not supported by ColdFusion.

In the end we just installed the ColdFusion-included Solr server (by re-installing ColdFusion, of course).

Also, they said the Solr server included with ColdFusion is the 3.4.x release. The ColdFusion Stand-alone Solr server is the same version. We probably could have installed the CF stand-alone server, but opted for the local server for simplicity (after all the trouble we had gone through already).

As a side note, it would be possible to use a different Solr server with ColdFusion, but you'd have to manage that server independently from ColdFusion. You could then query the server using `<cfhttp>`.

Comment: FYI there exists a CFSolrLib: http://www.jimleether.com/index.cfm/2013/1/20/A-Note-About-ColdFusion-and-Solr-40-Using-CFSolrLib